# vite rollup css background-img with reactive url image missing

Tags: css, vue.js

I have a vue3-vite project with a background missing issue

There is my vue project directory tree:

`src/assert/pic1.png`

`src/components/pages/Page1/Page1.vue`

I use a css background-img tag in Page1.vue : `background-image: url("src/assert/pic1.png")`

This setting in dev env it's worked, the request url is **http://.../src/assert/pic1.png**

But in test env the request url turn to **http://.../src/assets/src/assert/pic1.png**

I think maybe is sth wrong in roll up setting, but I don't know how to fix it...

Answer (score 2):

Add resolve.alias in vite.config by following.

https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#resolve-alias

vite.config.js

```
import path from "path";

// ...
resolve: {
  alias: {
    "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src")
  }
}
```

Page1.vue

```
background-image: url("@/assert/pic1.png")
```

Comment: Works for one backgourn image but unfortunately not for multiple.

Eg: `background-image: url("@/assert/pic1.png"), url("@/assert/pic2.png";`
Won't work

Answer (score 0):

found solution in https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html

1. Import pic path as backgroundUrl variable `import backgroundUrl from "~/assert/pic1.png"`
2. Set as variable in 'script' tag  `` const backgroundStyle = `background-image:url(${backgroundUrl})` ``
3. In target document element set reactive style `<div :style=backgroundStyle>`