# Vite and SASS url() path

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vite

I have a project using Vite.config.js. When I reference an image asset using CSS url() path, the console throws a 404 error after building the project. The path to the image works fine in HTML using img src, But it does not get the image from CSS utl() path. As I mentioned this happens after building the project with npm run build and then I preview it.

This is the SCSS. You can see the path of the image has to get back 3 folders at the beginning, which I think this is the reason why the build is not getting the images:

[image]

And this is my vite.config.js file where I think it comes the configuration to solve this problem:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({
    build: {
        minify: false,
        logLevel: 'info'
    }
});
```

And just in case this is my VSCode route:

[image]

Comment: You can try looking at this answer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73725281/vite-rollup-css-background-img-with-reactive-url-image-missing)